# How to determine page references in memory management

Tags: operating-system

I know how to use page references to determine a page fault using FIFO. I was confused if how to determine if we have FIFO table.

A process consists of six pages, 0 1 2 3 4 5. Page 0 is automatically loaded when we start running the program. Other pages are loaded (as they are referenced) by the page fault mechanism. This process is allowed only 3 pages in memory at any one time.
How to get a sequence of page references that this process can make (starting with 0, 2, 4)?  Asterisks represent page faults.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IFi2.jpg)

Comment: *What* operating system are we talking about? What *hardware platform*?

Comment: it is UNIX system POSIX

Comment: Which unix system?

Comment: AFAIK there are quite a lot of Unix or Unix-compatible systems in active development and deployment. Just saying "Unix" doesn't narrow it down really.

Comment: it's BSD system

Comment: How is that a programming question?

Comment: Page replacement strategy is implementation dependent What kind of strategy are you talking about? Whatever, when brought to memory bit is set to 1 just ensure that the page will not be too early replaced, if not high page fault rate will happen. But, this doesn't mean that this bit will stay so forever, there exists a strategy to set it to zero after sometime (lot of algorithms)